# Structured array in python

Tags: python, arrays, events, time, dynamic

I hope all is well.
I am trying to do a penalized cox regression analysis in Python.

Similar to:
https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/coxnet.html

However, in order for the function to work, the "event" and "time"
need to be stored as a structured array
similar to:

```
array([( True, 72.), ( True, 411.), ( True, 228.), ..., dtype=[('event', '?'), ('time', '<f8')])
```

I am struggling to do a structured array of the event and time.

So if I opened an excel sheet in python.
And in the excel sheet, I have a column for events, and another column for time, how cam I do a structured array?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

### The Data

Let's generate some fake data;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Date"] = np.random.choice(pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '2000-01-01'), 10)
df['Event'] = np.random.choice(range(100, 1000), 10)
```

```
        Date  Event
0 1986-11-09    613
1 1982-10-08    115
2 1991-09-13    680
3 1987-11-13    244
4 1998-06-22    250
5 1984-01-10    293
6 1998-05-02    887
7 1994-02-20    195
8 1995-09-19    374
9 1980-01-25    312
```

### As array

By selecting the two columns and using `.to_numpy()`, we create a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
array = df[['Date', 'Event']].to_numpy()
```

```
[[Timestamp('1986-11-09 00:00:00') 613]
 [Timestamp('1982-10-08 00:00:00') 115]
 [Timestamp('1991-09-13 00:00:00') 680]
 [Timestamp('1987-11-13 00:00:00') 244]
 [Timestamp('1998-06-22 00:00:00') 250]
 [Timestamp('1984-01-10 00:00:00') 293]
 [Timestamp('1998-05-02 00:00:00') 887]
 [Timestamp('1994-02-20 00:00:00') 195]
 [Timestamp('1995-09-19 00:00:00') 374]
 [Timestamp('1980-01-25 00:00:00') 312]]
```